# How to extract a description part from website with proper spacing?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have accessed the website with beautiful Soup and retrieved the description part(div class) but since it was in bulleted points. I receive an output like this without any spacings between points(Not Readable):

**DESCRIPTION:
COVID-19 ProjectionsGovernment-mandated social distancingHospital resource useAll bedsICU bedsInvasive ventilatorsDeaths per dayTotal deaths**

Actually I have both normal paragraph and bullet points so I cannot use **li** or **ul** to retrieve bullet points alone.

This is my program for this description part:

```
def DESCRIPTION(self):
    
    print('\n'+"DESCRIPTION: ")
    for j in Data_Set_Info.soup.select('.iH9v7b'):
        k = j.get_text()
        print ('\n'+k)
```

The HTML code for this webpage is:

```
<div class="iH9v7b"><p>COVID-19 Projections</p><ul><li>Government-mandated social distancing</li><li>Hospital resource use</li><ul><li>All beds</li><li>ICU beds</li><li>Invasive ventilators</li></ul><li>Deaths per day</li><li>Total deaths</li></ul><p></p></div>
```

The webpage is:`https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/search?query=health&docid=B2%2BtssYi2L2wvQwVAAAAAA%3D%3D`

In this website there are different dataset and each dataset have different description. I need to get all description in a proper spacing with single program. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get all the text with spaces in between, you can specify the character used to join text from different elements as an argument to `get_text`, like so:

```
k = j.get_text(' ')
```

If you want to be able to preserve (potentially nested) lists in the output then you'll need to recursively search through `j.contents`. A one-size-fits-all solution is unlikely to work for that purpose and will probably need a bit of experimentation.

Documentation links:

- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text
- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children